# Why can Excel grab content from a website, but I can't do the same with HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html

In the same way that I can get Excel to grab text from a website and copy it on a spreadsheet, I'd like to be able to do the same using HTML or JS code and paste it on my website.  I have no relationship with the target website and can't modify it.
I'm looking to copy the text in a `<td>` element and show it in my HTML file.
All the answers to similar questions require the domain to have CORS, which it doesn't.
Maybe if somebody knows how Excel pulls it off...

Comment: excel doesn't use a browser with security restrictions, which is why it works.   But it sounds like all you want is to use an html iframe tag.  Also, if you don't have control of the server, and the site you are trying to copy doesn't have instructions on embedding pages, then most likely you shouldn't be doing whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to access my company's webpage that displays reports, a list of invoices.  But there are three different reports in different pages, and I want to combine them all into one list.  It's not something that I couldn't do manually.  I tried Excel but I had problems with browser authentication, but I figured that if I've already opened the browser to use the HTML file, I wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Also, mine is not truly a "website" that would be open to the public, just a tool for my use that happens to be written in HTML/JS

Comment: forgot to thank you, user2263572, I got the data into my HTML file!  Now I need to figure out how I can use it.  I'll get to work on it and if I can't make it work I'll come back to stackOverflow.